# Wrong submit buttons get sent in POST with PHP script

Tags: php, html, forms

My PHP form uses multiple submit buttons that I use for A/B processing

Occasionally, the wrong submit buttons get passed on even though they are not the ones clicked. The buttons look like this:

```
<form method="post" action="url..." autocomplete="off">
... fields...
<input type="submit" name="UpdateExit" value="Exit" />
<input type="submit" name="UpdateSave" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="InsertNew" value="Insert new" />
<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" />            
<input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

Sometimes the `var_dump($_POST)` shows both `UpdateExit` and `UpdateSave` *even though* i clicked `InsertNew`! Needless to say it messes up the output. Then "the right button" is sent.

I narrowed down this behavior to webkit browsers and the first time I use the form after clearing my browser's cache, then it seems to "come back to normal". This is empirical and I cannot say it's PHP or HTML related. but I have been struggling with this for the better part of the day and found no spot on info on SO or elsewhere :(

Anyone heard/encountered a similar behavior?

Comment: try using `<button type="submit" name=""></button>` instead of `<input>` and tell what is the result

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<form method="post" action="url..." autocomplete="off">
... fields...
<input type="submit" name="UpdateExit" value="Exit" />
<input type="submit" name="UpdateSave" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" name="InsertNew" value="Insert new" />
<input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" />            
<input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

Handle Cancel logic as you would any of the other submit buttons.

PHP Form Handler Logic:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['UpdateExit'])) {
        //Do something based on Update and Exit was used
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['UpdateSave'])) {
        //Do something based on Update and Save was used
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['InsertNew'])) {
        //Do something based on Insert New was used
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
        //Do something based on Delete was used
    }
    else {
        //Do something because Cancel was used...
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is what I do. The problem is that when clicking InsertNew, the POST array shows `$_POST['UpdateSave']` and `$_POST['UpdateExit']` but only first time when coming in fresh to the form. Clearing cache.

Comment: Double check all of your names/variables again.

Comment: POST is a super global- maybe it's retaining the value from previous clicks in your code somehow...? You can clear it using $_POST = array();

Comment: Are you doing a proper [Post-Redirect-Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)?

Comment: Yes. However i am doing a var_dump($_POST) first thing way before the redirect. And this only happens one time in webkit after i clear all cache. then the proper submit buttons are being passed.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you have previous POST data in your request header still because PRG is not happening correctly.

Comment: So how come that all the POST data is what is being sent from the form except the "InsertNew" button that has been clicked which is not in the POST data while the "Update.." buttons are in the post data. Why would this happen only on a clean browser cache? Beats me...